# Do you have to pay to codesign an app on OS X?

Tags: macos, code-signing, code-signing-certificate

Due to the inclusion of [Gatekeeper](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht5290), you have to codesign your OS X apps (so your users won’t get a warning). It seems, though, that the only way to get it signed will involve paying the $99/year for a developer program. Is there a way to codesign an app for free?

Comment: Taking you literally, yes, you can sign with any certificate you want.  But to get past Gatekeeper, you need one from Apple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to get an app signed is to obtain a certificate from Apple for $99/year.